# Iterate through an AVL tree

Tags: java, avl-tree

I have implemented an AVL tree and I wanted to write an Iterator, that searches in pre order. I have this peace of code and I get always a NullPointer in "*stack.push(current)*" and dont know why

```
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

    return new Iterator<E>(){
        Node current;
        int counter;
        Stack<Node> stack;

        public void iterator() {
            counter++;
            stack = new Stack<Node>();
            current = root;
            stack.empty();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(counter == count(root)) return false;
            else return true;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            stack.push(current);
            counter++;
            if(current.left.value != null) return current.left.value;
            else return current.right.value;
        }

    };
}
```

Thanks in beforehand :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is `current = root;`? Where has root been instantiated?

Comment: This is just a segment of my whole code. At the beginning of my code i have instantiated the root

Answer (score 0):

Your `root` object was never declared or instantiated.  You are setting `current = root;` but in the current context, `root` is nothing.

```
public void iterator() {
        counter++;
        stack = new Stack<Node>();
        current = root;
        stack.empty();
    }
```

Comment: Even if I instantiate the root within my iterator and give him the value of the root or null, I also get an NullPointer. I can write him within the method, but which value I should use then?